# 'Know how' requirements for CNC / lathe manufacturing for open hardware projects

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, cnc

I've been asked to peer review a paper where the authors claim to be presenting an **open source hardware** item that is to be manufactured of aluminium using "CNC milling machines" or "standard lathes and milling machines". The maximum size of a part is 150 mm cubed. There are many parts involved.

However they only supply a series of STEP CAD files for the parts and no instructions for manufacture whatsoever. They claim the parts can alternatively be purchased from a single company which is part of the authorship (and declared in CoI). I can't give more details due to pre-publication confidentiality.

Since I have little experience with metalworking manufacturing my question to you is:

**What minimum documentation of 'know how' should be provided for such a project, making complex mechanical parts out of aluminium?**

For example, should details of the model of suitable lathes/CNC machines be provided? Are there any special machine files or other documentation required? Or is it reasonable to expect that any specialist aluminium metalworker can just make parts from STP files without further manufacturing know how info?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have no idea of how to make things or program / use CNC then why would you accept to peer review this paper?

Comment: @Solar Mike because I have considerable expertise in open source for hardware for FDM 3D printing and in the the subject matter of the use of the thing being made. This is also 'only' one aspect of the paper which contains other aspects not related to CNC machining.

Comment: I can't ask my 2 sons who could do that because you don't give sufficient info... They can read the files and decide how to make the pieces as they are "polymecanicians".

Comment: I'm closing this question because it isn't really about engineering. The "minimum documentation that should be provided" is a matter to be decided by the journal that would be publishing the paper. Is the journal's audience one that's probably fluent in such matters or no? Even if not, there isn't a "code" that dictates such things, it's a question of what the journal will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An STP file is basically a drawing isn't it? People can make parts from drawings, but not blindly. That's one reason why 3D printing is so attractive: 3D printers approach all parts the same way so you can directly feed them the STP file. Not so with machine tools. There's thousands of machines, tools, and approaches that can be used to make the same part with various tradeoffs in precision, speed, set up time, and initial investment. You have to sit down and work out the processes, tooling, and fixturing you want, and the order. Translating a drawing to a production process is its own big thing.

> What minimum documentation of 'know how' should be provided for such a project, making complex mechanical parts out of aluminium?

Depends on what you mean by "minimum".

You could argue the drawing is the minimum...a bit lacking though if it doesn't have tolerances specfied and such. Just add process design experience.

Then there is the process manual which details the step-by-step the tooling and operation to be performed on the part, intermediary drawings, and tolerancing. Not cheap to develop, and also specific to the equipment you have available, but also not necessarily the only way to make to a part and not something you leave laying around. Used in industries like aerospace. I've been told each part actually has an its own copy of the manual following it around where the measurements after each process are filled in and signed off on.